# Request wont read the hole web stite

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Im tryning to get a span from this web site.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('https://www.nbim.no/').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

find = soup.find("span", id="liveNavNumber")
print(find)
```

[image]
Here is what im trying to get. But reqest wont read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source for the page (*not* the live tree, as your screenshot indicates), you can see that there's only

```
<span aria-live="off" id="liveNavNumber"></span><span class="currency">nok</span>
```

in the markup you receive.

The actual market value number is added dynamically.

Looking at the network inspector, you can see a request being made to the URL https://www.nbim.no/LiveNavHandler/Current.ashx?l=en-GB (I've removed some parameters that don't actually matter, it seems), which returns JSON data:

```
{
    "d": {
        // ... lots of uninteresting data ...
    },
    "Value": "10 263 798 821 956",
    "Date": "10/06/2020 14:09:10"
}
```

So, if you're interested in that Value, you can just

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get("https://www.nbim.no/LiveNavHandler/Current.ashx?l=en-GB")
>>> data = r.json()
>>> print(data["Value"])
10 253 757 444 193
>>>
```